# Mount image multiple times in docker

Tags: windows, docker, neo4j, dockerfile

As far as I understand Docker, it should be very simple to create different environments like dev or prod by just mounting an image multiple times by just running "docker run" more than once.

However, I've build an image extending neo4j to have a custom configured neo4j image with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM neo4j:3.5
COPY neo4j.conf /var/lib/neo4j/conf/neo4j.conf
COPY apoc-3.5.0.1.jar /var/lib/neo4j/plugins/apoc.jar
```

I've build it with

```
docker build -t myneo .
```

Now I'v started it 2 times using a script.bat like so:

```
docker run -d --rm --name neo4j-prod -p 10074:7474 -p 10087:7687 myneo
docker run -d --rm --name neo4j-dev -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 myneo
```

Now I have 2 instances reachable under :10074 and :7474, however, when I create some date in one of those, it appears in the other one as well. What am I doing wrong?
Sadly, I have to work on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Looks like your both Neo4j instances are pointing to the same database on the file system.**

You can change the database location in `neo4j.conf` file.
By default database is stored in `data` directory.

You can uncomment following line and change it as per your env.

```
#dbms.directories.data=data
```

like

```
dbms.directories.data=prod_data
```

Another option is to keep the database location the same and use the different databases for prod and dev.

You can uncomment and change the active database name on the following line.

```
#dbms.active_database=graph.db
```

like

```
dbms.active_database=prod_graph.db
```

**EDIT:**
If above is not the issue then, maybe you are connecting to the same host from Neo4j browser (check host in bolt connection).

**Refer following screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: But aren't containers independent from one another? So shouldn't it be irrelevant, that the path to the data folder is the same for both?

Comment: This is relevant if the database is stored on the host machine which is running these containers. If data is stored within containers then this should not be an issue.

Comment: Are you creating these nodes from Neo4j browser?

Comment: The data is stored in the container. And yes I'm creating the nodes from the browser, but from the two different browsers under ports 7474 and 10074

Comment: And you are connecting to the right host(highlighted part) as shown in the above screenshot?

Comment: That was exactly the problem, thank you. I've missed it, since I've disabled authentication, but the bolt resorts to 7687 by default.

Answer (score 1):

If your issue was due to copying the same config file which might contaib common data then you might consider changing thecway you modify it for separate environments.

According to [Configuration](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/docker/configuration/) docs. There are multiple way to customize the config file - *copying the file which you are using is one of them* - but as you intend to use the same image for multiple environment it would be better to also configure neo4j based on environment variables to avoid making the same configuration for both like passwords or databases and so on, for example:

```
docker run \
    --detach \
    --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
    --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data \
    --volume=$HOME/neo4j/logs:/logs \
    --env=NEO4J_dbms_memory_pagecache_size=4G \
    neo4j:3.5
```

And your Dockerfile will be like this:

```
FROM neo4j:3.5
COPY apoc-3.5.0.1.jar /var/lib/neo4j/plugins/apoc.jar
```

So you might want to enable database authentication in production but not in development then you will have to do the following:

```
# For production
docker run -d --rm --name neo4j-prod -e NEO4J_dbms.security.auth_enabled=true -p 10074:7474 -p 10087:7687 myneo

# For development
docker run -d --rm --name neo4j-dev -e NEO4J_dbms.security.auth_enabled=false -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 myneo
```

Following this way will make easy to deploy, reconfigure and keeping the configuration separate, also when you go with something like [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) things will be easier.

More details can be found in [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/docker/configuration/#docker-environment-variables)